# When to capture a UILabel's height?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to capture a UILabel's height in an instance variable.  I'm using a default style `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`.

As of now, I try to capture the height when the cell is created in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The code (skipped the deque'd stuff for brevity):

```
UITableViewCell *testCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"] autorelease];

testCell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
testCell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 10;

testCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

testCell.textLabel.text = @"LabelName";
testCell.detailTextLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"key"];
[testCell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];  //still says 0.00 :-(

labelHeight = testCell.detailTextLabel.bounds.size.height;
NSLog(@"testCell height is %f", testCell.detailTextLabel.bounds.size.height);  // equals 0.00
NSLog(@"cellFrame is %f", testCell.frame); //also says 0.00
return cell;
```

The `NSLog` states the height is 0.00.

So, where is a good place to capture a label's height?  Or, what am I missing?  I would think the `detailTextLabel` bounds would be set when I assign it `[someObject valueForKey:theKey]`.  Thanks!

EDIT:  For complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the all of the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
I suspect you're not giving the detailTextLabel a frame (or bounds) that is non-zero.
You could also NSLog the cell.frame to see what it's width and height are.

Comment: You're never assigning the detailTextLabel a frame, so it's defaulting to zero.  You need something like this     testCell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,30);  and then    [testCell addSubview:detailTextLabel];      OR    add detailTextLabel as a subview and then size to fit.  FINALLY, NSLog(@" cell frame: %f,%f %f,%f", cell.frame.origin.x,cell.frame.origin.y,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height);    will tell you the truth about the cell frame.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `[cell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit]` before assigning `labelHeight`? My understanding is that the label will be sized at that point and you should get a nonzero value back (assuming the text is not empty.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the NSLog still showed the height as 0.00.